# Python selenium select element by class

Tags: python, selenium, element

I tried to select an element with selenium but I'm a beginner.

Here is the element that I tried to select :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-form">
    Connexion
</button>
```

I tried this lines on my script :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://skysand.fr")

connexion_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("login")
connexion_button.click()

email_input = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
email_input.send_keys("XXXX")

password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password_input.send_keys("XXXX")

connect_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-primary btn-block btn-form")
connect_button.click()
```

But it is not working :(

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (513, 955)

Thanks if you can help me !
(sorry for my bad English...)

Comment: Are you running in regular or headless mode? can you share all your code?

Comment: I don't know :(
I edited my question to show you all the code

Comment: I see. Now it's OK. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select element by multiple class names you should use css_selector or XPath. Also, for this element it would better to use this css locator:

```
button[type='submit']
```

So try this:

```
connect_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selectro("button[type='submit']")
connect_button.click()
```

Also, this your code needs waits. With them it will look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://skysand.fr")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".login"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#email"))).send_keys("XXXX")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#password"))).send_keys("XXXX")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

Comment: It's working ! I have just a new error : 
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (513, 923)`

But I think it's a problem of the site, it's weird because you can click it manually... 
Anyhow, thanks for your help

Comment: See the updated answer. Let me know if now it works correct?

Comment: I also added `driver.maximize_window()` method. This should resolve this problem.